# FragmentActivity.getSupportMediaController() is deprecated

Tags: android, mediacontroller

For getting a `MediaControllerCompat` instance I'm using `getSupportMediaController()` in `FragmentActivity`. But this method is deprecated. Which method do I have to use instead of this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check the Android official docs .. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

It tells you everything.

According to Android Developer documentation :

> This method is deprecated.Use getMediaController() instead. 
>       This API will be removed in a future release.

So you have to use `getMediaController()` instead of `getSupportMediaController()`

To support devices older than SDK level 21 use `MediaControllerCompat.getMediaController(activity)`

Comment: This does not provide MediaControllerCompat (the compatibility version of MediaController) to offer support to devices older than SDK level 21. Use `MediaControllerCompat.getMediaController(activity)` instead.

Answer (score 9):

If you still want a MediaControllerCompat instance there is a way to get it since `getMediaController()` doesn't return the compatibility version of this class:

```
MediaControllerCompat.getMediaController(activity)
```

I found this info in the Revision 26.0.0 Beta 1 of Support Library changelog:

> FragmentActivity.setSupportMediaController() and FragmentActivity.getSupportMediaController() have been removed. Please use the new static MediaControllerCompat.setMediaController() and MediaControllerCompat.getMediaController() methods.